# Reading file byte by byte starting from a specific position of a file

Tags: python-2.7

i want to read 1000 bytes after i found *strA* in file. but i am getting the error

> ValueError: Mixing iteration and read methods would lose data

please provide your inputs for the same.

Here is the code:

```
input_file=open("abcd.txt",'rb')
strA = ">>>>>>>>>> message sent(1000 bytes)"
with input_file as myFile:
    for num, line in enumerate(myFile):
        if strA in line:
            bytes = line.split('(')
            byte1 =bytes[1]
            byte2 =byte1[0:4]
            print byte2
            print line
            a=int(byte2)
            data = input_file.read(a)
            print data
            break
```

Comment: Did you mean `open("abcd.txt", "rb")` in the first line?

Comment: yes i am reading a txt file in binary mode.

Comment: and it's the same that you had written.

Comment: ... Why not just not iterate?